# How to disable Execute-only Memory in Android Studio project with gradle and cmake?

Tags: android, gradle, cmake

Begin with API level 29, Execute-only Memory is enabled by default for all 64-bit binaries on Android platform. Unfortunately, our project depends on a lot of third-party libraries that don't support this and will cause the app crash. We need to disable Execute-only Memory globally for our project. The [document](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/execute-only-memory#disabling) says we can disable it with `make -j ENABLE_XOM=false`. How can we do this in gradle or cmake?

Comment: Hi, did you find the answer to this?

Comment: @AmolJindal not yet. I asked this in android-ndk forum https://groups.google.com/g/android-ndk/c/6xTuTkguftY. They said this should already be removed. We updated the SDK and target SDK level and compile SDK level. So far this problem has gone.

Comment: Which targetSDK version and compileSDK version is working for you?

Comment: targetSDK and compileSDK Both 29

Comment: But as you mentioned in the original question, you faced this issue with API 29, so how is it working now for you?
Did you make any other change? Build tools version or something else?

Comment: In our first try. the compile sdk version is 28. only target sdk version is 29. I don't know if that's the reason.

Comment: Thank you. Can you also tell me your build tools version and NDK version?
I am using compileSDK and targetSDK version 29 for both and i am getting the crash.

Comment: We use Android Studio 4.0 with ndk r16b.

Answer (score 0):

The XOM is enabled by default with target API 29. Kernel disables XOM for compatibility with older target APIs.

Have you tried using cmake in the [build tool mode](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/manual/cmake.1.html#build-tool-mode)? Options specified after `--` are passed to the native tool.

`cmake --build <dir> [<options>] -- ENABLE_XOM=false`